# Displaying UIDatePicker as Popover within UITableView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I would like display a date picker with a `UIModalPresentationPopover` presentation style, and while it's working fine on an iPad, it results in a black screen when displayed on an iPhone. *Edit*: Specifically, it is simply presented full screen, so the effect is a black screen unless I add colours to elements manually. The default colours work fine for Popover presentation.

The code generating the picker and the popover is:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .DateAndTime
datePicker.minuteInterval = 5

let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view.addSubview(datePicker!)
vc.preferredContentSize = datePicker.frame.size
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1))
let ppc = vc.popoverPresentationController
ppc?.delegate = self
ppc?.sourceRect = cell.accessoryView!.frame
ppc?.sourceView = cell

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The value of `cell` appears correct on both types of devices, but I notice that the size of the view of the presented `viewController` gets messed up on the iPhone. After presentation is finished, the value of `preferredContentSize` property is `(320.0, 216.0)` on both devices, but  `view.frame.size` becomes `(320.0, 568.0)` on the iPhone (which is full screen on iPhone 5, and it acts similarly on iPhone as well), while on iPad it still matches the preferred size.

Looks great on iPad:

[image: Looks great on iPad]

I've had no trouble presenting the same kind of UI from a `UIViewController` that was not `UITableViewController`. Is there anything else that needs to be done to allow this style of presentation with a tableView on an iPhone?

***Edit***
Fixed. To allow this, need to add a method to the presenting controller:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found on the docs from `UIViewController`

> `modalPresentationStyle`
>
> The presentation style determines how a modally
>   presented view controller is displayed onscreen. In a horizontally
>   compact environment, modal view controllers are always presented
>   full-screen

What you can do is, on the iPhone, set the `backgroundColor` of the view to black with `.15 alpha, and position the picker at the bottom.

You might need to set `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`, because otherwise it removes the views underneath.